# Access denied when trying to connect to mysql database via eclipse, java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I'm trying to connect to mysql database, but I get one and the same error: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

### I've already tried the following solutions:

1. Checked my username and password. MySQL connection is established via username = user1, password = 123. I use the same in my code, when I connect to the database: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
   "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee","user1", "123");`
2. Granted privileges to user1 in the following manner:
   `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user1'@'localhost';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

   By the way I have the same problem when I try to connect with 'root'@'localhost'.
   Do you have any ideas why it doesn't work still?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database using a SQL Client and the provided user and password?

Comment: @ngueno sure, I have checked my connection via MySQL Workbench by entering username = user1 and password = 123

Comment: Give a try to `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee?user=user1&password=123");`

Comment: If it fails try without the `employee` database, just `localhost:3306`

Comment: @ngueno well at lest I get a new mistake now: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 2 (çèìà)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
What is this now??

Comment: @ngueno I have solved the problem. Your solution as well as the marked answer are suitable for my case. Thank you so much!

Comment: Pleasure to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL JDBC is only able to connect via TCP/IP (on Unix, or TCP/IP or named pipe on Windows).

The MySQL JDBC driver cannot establish a connection using the local unix socket.

With MySQL on Unix, `localhost` has a different meaning that we might expect. It is not a hostname synonym for the 127.0.0.1 TCP/IP loopback address.  On Unix, MySQL user

```
'user1'@'localhost'
```

specifies a user that can connect only via unix socket file; it's not possible to connect to that user via TCP/IP.

---

The above explains why MySQL is refusing a connection from JDBC: the connection attempt fails because a matching user does not exist.

To create a MySQL user that connect from TCP/IP loopback address, assuming that MySQL is started with `--skip-name-resolve` and without `--skip-networking`, we can specify user as:

```
'user'@'127.0.0.1'
```

That user would allow connection from JDBC.

(If MySQL DNS name resolution is enabled, then we would need to use a hostname that resolves to the loopback address; or we can consider using a wildcard '%' for the hostname portion of the user.)

Comment: Thank you, now I get this mistake: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 2 (çèìà)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
How can this be solved?

Comment: I've solved the problem! Now everything is correct) thanks a lot for your help! To fix the new error I executed these commands in MySQL Workbench: SET @@global.time_zone = '+00:00';

SET @@session.time_zone = '+00:00';

Answer (score 0):

Try this out might help:

1) goto mysql terminal. 2) mysql> use mysql; 3) mysql> select user, host from user; 4) There next to you user set the host as "%" instead of localhost

.

now in the connection instead of localhost tryp specifying the ip address of the server.

Hope this helps you. :)